# Tracing mallocs in xcode instruments

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments

I'm familiar with using xcode to profile memory allocations, however I'm currently working on a project that uses a lot of Core Graphics and it seems that most of the allocations simply show up as "Malloc x bytes"

Is there a way to trace where each malloc is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select any Category, press `Command + E` or `View -> Extended Detail`